# Display an additional field only if it is filled

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, echo

On the wordpress site, the store metadata is displayed through additional fields with this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'art_get_text_field_before_add_card' );
function art_get_text_field_before_add_card() {
    global $post;
    ?>
    <span class="text-field">
        Shelf life: <a><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_product_text_field', true ); ?> m.</a><br><br>
        Volume: <a><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_product_text_field2', true ); ?> gr.</a>
    
    </span>
    <?php
}
```

Can you please tell me how I can improve the code so that the lines "Shelf life" and "Volume" are displayed on the site only when the metadata is filled (_custom_product_text_field and _custom_product_text_field2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in many ways, this is just one

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'art_get_text_field_before_add_card');
function art_get_text_field_before_add_card() {
    global $post;
?>
    <span class="text-field">
        <?php if (!empty($text_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_product_text_field', true))) : ?>
        Shelf life: <a><?= $text_field; ?> m.</a><br><br>
        <?php
        endif;

        if (!empty($text_field2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_product_text_field2', true))) :
        ?>
        Volume: <a><?= $text_field2; ?> gr.</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </span>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding to my question. Your solution helped me my errors in code. If I can help you with anything, let me know.

Comment: You should update the answer to not use `<?=` as the correct use is `<?php echo `. Shorthand for php opening tag is deprecated in the current PHP version (and future)

Comment: @MortenBak When you say current PHP version? which version do you mean? 8?. Could you point me to the article where it says that PHP shorthand <?= will be deprecated?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast 

https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/3972 PHP 7.4 Deprecation Notice Implementation
https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/3975 PHP 8.0 Removal Implementation
TBD Documentation patch

And: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags

Comment: This seems like the removal of the <? ?> tags as valid options, not <?= ?>. from PHP docs. `As short tags can be disabled it is recommened to only use the normal tags (<?php ?> and <?= ?>) to maximise compatibility.`. Source: [PHP tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)